# Magento 2.7 and 2.1.1 - While changing the password form the my account page User group changed to default customer group

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

While changing the password from the my account page user group changed to default customer group. 
For example : 
1) I have created Customer group named "XXXX Group"
2) I have created a user with "XXXX Group" from admin panel.
3) When i change the password from the my account change password section, the current user group has been assigned to default User group.
Note:
I have checked both the versions 2.0.7 and 2.1.1, which facing the same issue.
kindly provide the solution

Expectation: When i change the password, user must be assigned to expected "XXXX Group"

Answer (score 1):

Beware, i did not consider old customer data in the event dispatch, old data is new data, for me it works so far.

### app/code/VENDOR/Customer/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VENDOR_Customer" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

### app/code/VENDOR/Customer/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- for restoring group id after password reset -->
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository">
        <plugin name="VENDOR_customer_model_resourcemodel_customerrepository_plugin"
                type="VENDOR\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Plugin"
                sortOrder="10"
                disabled="false"/>
    </type>
```

### app/code/VENDOR/Customer/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VENDOR_Customer',
    __DIR__
);
```

---

### app/code/VENDOR/Customer/Model/ResourceModel/CustomerRepository/Plugin.php

```
<?php

namespace VENDOR\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository;
use Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;

class Plugin
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog */
    private $_logger;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface */
    private $_eventManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        Monolog $logger,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager
    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_eventManager = $eventManager;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function aroundSave(
        CustomerRepository $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        CustomerInterface $customer,
        $passwordHash)
    {
        $prevCustomerData = null;
        if ($customer->getId()) {
            $prevCustomerData = $subject->getById($customer->getId());
            $groupId = $prevCustomerData->getGroupId();
        }

        $customer = $proceed($customer, $passwordHash);
        if (isset($groupId)) {
            $customer->setGroupId($groupId);
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'customer_save_after_data_object',
                [
                    'customer_data_object' => $customer,
                    'orig_customer_data_object' => $customer
                ]
            );
        }

        return $customer;
    }
}
```